# Uniform convergence does not closed under multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

> Construct sequences $\{f_n\}$, $\{g_n\}$ which converge uniformly in some set $E$, but such that $\{f_ng_n\}$ does not converge uniformly on $E$ (of course, $\{f_ng_n\}$ must converge on $E$).

**My example:** Let's $E=(0,1)$ and $f_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}, g_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{n+x^{-1}}.$

Then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E$ since $M_n=\sup\limits_{E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$. Also $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly on $E$ since $|g_n(x)|=\dfrac{1}{n+x^{-1}}\le \dfrac{1}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

But $f_n(x)g_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{nx+1}$ does not converges unifromly on $E$ since $M_n=\sup\limits_{E}|f_n(x)g_n(x)|\ge f_n(\frac{1}{n})g_n(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2}.$

What you think about above example? I would be grateful to anyone's opinion.

Comment: $f_n(x)=g_n(x)=x-1/n$ on $\Bbb R$ would also work.

Comment: @Arthur, Nice example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you proved is that the sequence $(f_ng_n)$ cannot converge uniformly to $0$. Maybe we then need an argument which say that since $f_ng_n\to 0$ pointwise, then the unique potential uniform limit is the null function.

Otherwise, your counter-example is fine.

Comment: Yes really! Limit function of $\{f_n(x)g_n(x)\}$ if null function.